# No signal after shutdown

Tags: linux-mint

Recently, I was watching some videos on youtube and my pc froze ( It is a really old PC ). I just removed the power cable directly from the electric board. After some time, I turned on my pc, the fans turned on but there was no signal on the monitor. I checked the cables, cleaned and reseated the RAM sticks, reset the CMOS, checked every cable and even removed everything from the motherboard and again add everything back ( Idk why I did that lol ) but still the problem was there. Can someone help me?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop

Comment: I would but I don't want to waste more money on it. I would rather get a new laptop or a new pc. ( Its a 15 years old pc anyways ). I still want to do common stuff such as using as using it as a storage device.

Comment: Does it at least beep when powered on? (Also, is the GPU integrated or separate?)

Comment: The GPU is intergrated. And it doesn't beep or something..

Comment: 1. There's never a reason to do what you did - *I just removed the power cable* -; even with a completely unresponsive OS you can press and hold the power button. 2. Take it to a repair shop -> Asking random people on the web won't help; troubleshooting in this case needs to be hands-on and with parts to try in an "trial and error" process.

Comment: I don't remember if I removed the power cable or used the power button. Most probably I hold the power button as thats what I do. Its a old home server and I can't spend money on it as its really old and most probably its un-fixable as the motherboard died.